# Byte array to blob in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database in mysql. In this I have a table which is storing image in blob format.
From my Java program I want to insert a new image into the table.
But When I tried to convert a `byte[]` to blob using

```
java.sql.Blob blob=null;
blob.setBytes(1, myByte );
```

I am getting null pointer exception.

Again tried by converting:

```
 Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(bytes);
```

But here also got exception wrong format.

Comment: try with the connection Blob blob = connection.createBlob();

Comment: I tried but I got exception                                               java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createBlob()Ljava/sql/Blob;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you use this code:

```
java.sql.Blob blob=null;
blob.setBytes(1, myByte );
```

`blob` is null. You have to create a new Blob Object like:

```
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(myByte );
```

and then you can store it.

Comment: I tried the same thing as you specified ..But I am getting this Error                                                             You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Image``='javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@1229be35' where `PeopleId = 'xxx' at line 1

Comment: @DRD Can you please show the code where you use the blob?

Comment: String imageVal = hexToString(peopleData.getImage());
  byte[] image =(imageVal).getBytes();
  java.sql.Blob blob=null;
  try {
   blob = new SerialBlob(image);
   //blob.setBytes(1, image );
  } catch (SQLException e1) {
  }
  String query = "UPDATE `peopleimage` SET ``Image``='" +blob + "' where `PeopleId = '"+ peopleData.getId() + "'";
  try {
   stmt = con.createStatement();
   stmt.execute(query);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
  }

Comment: @DRD use prepared statement. Here is an [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html) how you can do this.

Comment: Again error                                                           com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Image``='javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@418ae96e' where `PeopleId = '8a8887d' at line 1

Comment: When I used Serial Blob and prepared statement I got com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Image``='javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@1c58478b' where `PeopleId = '8a8887d' at line 1

Comment: this is the code
  System.out.println("peopleData.getImage()"+peopleData.getImage());
  byte[] image =(peopleData.getImage()).getBytes();
  java.sql.Blob blob =null ;
  try {
   blob = new SerialBlob(image );
    blob.setBytes(1, image);
  } catch (SQLException e1) {
  }
  String query = "UPDATE `peopleimage` SET ``Image``='" + blob + "' where `PeopleId = '"
    + peopleData.getId() + "'";
  java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  try {
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
  }

Comment: when i used  blob = con.createBlob(); i got java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createBlob()Ljava/sql/Blob;

Comment: @DRD what you are doing is not a prepared statement. try this code: `String query = "UPDATE peopleimage SET Image= ?  where `PeopleId = ?"; 
  java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 
  try { 
   pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
   pstmt.setBlob(1, blob);
   pstmt.setInt((2, peopleData.getId());
   pstmt.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e) { }   }`

Comment: Thank you Jens for ur quick replies..I solved my problem using prepared statement. I have one doubt what is the difference between normal statement and prepared statement in this scenario